# nodejs project dependencies synchronization

Tags: node.js

I am creating a nodejs project and wish to have same library versions used across dev, qa, staging and production environment.

Tried package.json but was unable to find good help. Need some suggestion here.

EDITED

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "ioredis": "1.7.5",
        "redis": "0.12.1",
        "redis-hash": "0.0.4",
        "debug": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "Tried package.json", what did you try and what problem are you having??

Comment: You just specify the exact version in your dependecies

Comment: @leemo - seems my template for package.json is not right, can you help in getting right link for readup

Comment: @Pawan can you post it here? Or just google the structure of the file yourself?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin - edited post and added the package.json

Comment: @Pawan so what's the problem? Your debug package can have different version because you specified it to have the most recent

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin - it worked now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your dependencies using the exact versions in the `package.json` file, and when you run `npm install`  it will get the proper versions of all your dependencies.

If you don't specifiy an exact version for the libraries, there's a chance that there's a new version since the last time you ran the command, you will end up with different versions of your libraries on your servers, which might not be what you want.

NPM has an `outdated`  command which will list all the dependencies that have fallen behind and need to be updated. You can then run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks @Drown - is the format which I have used correct?